# Connect to SFTP dynamically in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a logic app created in Azure which has 2 SFTP connections, is it possible to dynamically connect to the correct one based on the parameter?

[image]

The idea is that based on the SFTPConnection parameter (shown above) at step 1, the logic app can then use the appropriate SFTP Connection in step 2

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.  Questions around dynamically selecting a connection have been asked before and I don't think anything has ever surfaced where you can do it at runtime.  If you find a way, be sure to share!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not supported seems like there is an feedback request already made in [Support Dynamic API connection in Logic app designer](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a968c61e-8126-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789). You may upvote this recommendation to request it to be implemented as soon as possible.